# Bullet Prefab Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am getting an error in this script?

UnityEngine does not contain a definition for rigid body (Lines: 22,24)

```
public class GunShoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject BulletPrefab;
    public float BulletSpeed;
    public int BulletsInClip;
    public AudioClip GunshotSound;

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Shoot")){

            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot() {

        var bullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab, transform.Find("BulletSpawn").position, transform.Find("BulletSpawn").rotation);
        bullet.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * BulletSpeed);
        audio.PlayOneShot(GunshotSound);
        BulletsInClip--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `var` in this case means that the created instance is of type `UnityEngine.Object`. You need to specify a type cast explicitly:

```
var bullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab) as GameObject;
```

or

```
var bullet = (GameObject) Instantiate(BulletPrefab);
```

In general it is preferrable to use an explicit type as it increases readability (my oppinion) like:

```
GameObject bullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab) as GameObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Unity you need to grab the rigidbody like  this`bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody >().AddForce(...)` -- this is c# btw I'm not sure how different it is in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) to get the RigidBody something like this.

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * BulletSpeed);
```